# Get subtrees from a starting encoded tree

Tags: python, design-patterns, tree

I have trees coded like this:

`A ➜ B ➜ C ➜ -1 ➜ D`

`A ➜ B ➜ C ➜ -1 ➜ -1 ➜ D`

When there is `-1`, it means that you have to go up one level, so in the first example, `B` has two children (`C` and `D`). In the second example, `A` has two children (`B` and `D`).

My goal is to remove one leaf at a time and get the remaining tree, referring to the first example, there are two leaves (`C` and `D`), so what I want to get is:

`A ➜ B ➜ D`

`A ➜ B ➜ C`

Referring to the second example, there are always two leaves (`C` and `D`), so what I want to get is:

`A ➜ B ➜ -1 ➜ D`

`A ➜ B ➜ C`

I've written some intricate code, but it doesn't work for all applications, do you have something in mind, or is there already some library that does this job?

Comment: What do you mean by coded like this: `A -> B -> C -> -1 -> D`. Do you mean a list, string, what?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a string

Comment: Why not just `A -> D` instead of `A -> B -> -1 -> D` for second example?

Comment: Because if you remove `C`, the remaining tree is `A -> B -> -1 -> D`

Comment: What will be the output for `A -> B -> C -> -1 -> -1 -> D -> E -> -1 -> -1 -> F`?

Comment: The output for your tree should be: `A ➜ B ➜ -1 ➜ D ➜ E ➜ -1 ➜ -1 ➜ F`, `A ➜ B ➜ C ➜ -1 ➜ -1 ➜ D ➜ -1 ➜ F` and `A ➜ B ➜ C ➜ -1 ➜ -1 ➜ D ➜ E`

Comment: Is `A -> B -> -1 -> -1 -> C` a valid string or is the first node guaranteed to be an only root node?

Comment: `A -> B -> -1 -> -1 -> C` is not a valid string

Comment: What is the output for `A ➜ B ➜ C ➜ -1 ➜ -1 ➜ -1 ➜ D`?

Comment: @DaniMesejo this is not a valid tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that in your notation, a leaf is either a label at the very end of the description, or a label in the context `➜ [X] ➜ -1`. In either case, you could remove the leaf:

- if the label is at the end, remove it and the ➜ which precedes it (if there is one) and then repeatedly remove `➜ -1` if that appears at the end of the description.
- If the label is in the context `➜ [X] ➜ -1`, remove those four tokens.

Comment: I think that covers all cases. If you have a counterexample, feel free to leave a comment here.

Comment: I just wrote the code and everything seems to work, thanks!